# Largest sailing vessel manned by 2 people

Tags: internal-consistency, transportation, ships, shipbuilding, sea

I am currently running a D&D campaign and am entering an area that doesn't have many set rules and I'd like a reality check. I want to give them a vessel around the size of the ones from Pirates of the Caribbean, but I feel like there has to be a good reason they have large crews that large. That being said, two people did try to steal the Black Pearl at one point so maybe they could get away with 5? Anyway, here are the details.

**World**

The world is pretty full of magic. Specifically, the country they are in is the largest magical hub within at least 500 miles. The continent they are on is about the size of North America, is kinda round, and has a LOT of islands surrounding it. They are not visible from the mainland and range in size from Hawaii to Australia. Pirates are a pretty big problem in the area they are about to sail through and I need to take that into account. That being said, the crew themselves are pretty well equipped to deal with opponents...

**Crew**

Two of them are very experienced with being at sea (grew up at sea, was captain of a ship for almost a decade). The rest have never been on a boat, but I'm not going to have any of them get sea sick. All of them have significantly above average strength, dexterity, and intelligence (they're descended from demigods essentially).

My players are about to purchase a boat at a port and I am curious about several things.

1. Can you even buy a boat at a port?
2. What is the largest sea vessel they can physically man with only 5 people? (if possible a specific classification)
3. What about the largest vessel if they had magical help to propel them?
4. About how fast is that boat for long trips (without magical assistance)?
5. Would pirates go after a ship that has no cargo and a small crew more or less than the average ship?

I'm pretty stumped on this because I know nothing about sailing or historic sea travel. An answer to even just one of my questions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Edit: Technology can go up to the late 1700s, but definitely not past that. Budget is not an obstacle either. Two of the crew members are children of sea gods so we can assume they will always have decent conditions. Additionally, they have a druid among them who is also well versed in dealing with weather so they can predict storms up to a week in advance.

Edit 2: D&D specifics: We're running version 5e. The characters are all level 4, but they have the base stats of a character that is WELL past level 20 (one has a strength of 30). They are all demi-gods but are not well trained in combat. Classes: Barbarian, Warlock, Druid, Ranger, and Paladin. The Barbarian and the Paladin are the ones well versed in sea travel.

Comment: How advanced is their technology?

Comment: What is the level and classes of the characters?

Comment: Based on Pirates, a crew of 6-7 would be enough to fully man the ship. But Jack and Will did sail a boat out with the two of them. If possible can you limit your question down to a single main world building question? Some are simple enough... 1. Yes, usually from a boat owner or renting. Boats didn't just sit in a harbor like car dealerships. 3. depends heavily on magic. 5. Pirates don't know your ship has no cargo and a smaller crew makes it easier to target. Big ships also mean more wealth so you would appear to be easy prey.

Comment: I will be watching this thread closely for the next hour. Any questions people ask in the comments I will add as edits to the post. Do a refresh after a couple minutes and I should have responses up! @Shadowzee, my big issue is that I am unsure how to describe the ship and its general specifications. Would it be out of the question to have a 120 ft. ship with multiple floors?

Comment: @MichaelZiluck I have no idea. I'm not really a Ship person. Just liked Pirates of the Caribbean.

Comment: This isn't an answer from a worldbuilding perspective, but D&D has rules for this in the Unearthed Arcana. https://media.wizards.com/2018/dnd/downloads/UA_ShipsSea.pdf

Comment: There are too many questions in here. I recommend removing all but question 2 of your list. Our policy is one question per question. You can ask follow on questions (as to the ability to buy a boat and what speed you can make) later.

Comment: one question per post please, else it is too broad.

Comment: The number of people needed to sail a sailing ship or boat depends a lot on the size of the vessel and the rig.  A fore and aft rig required less manpower to handle the sails than a square rig did.  Sailors could raise or lower the sails by pulling on ropes from the deck, and the most recent ones had small steam engines to do the pulling.  So the giant seven masted schooner, Thomas W. Lawson,  had a crew of only 18.  Chinese junk rigs could also be set from the deck.  So it all depends on the size, the rig, and the amount of technological or magical work automation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One of the key problems that you have with a small crew is the heavy lifting. The reason why a ship of the line used to have a crew of 500 to 750, and a modern container ship can get away with a crew of as few as 20 is mechanisation. A large ship carries a large anchor for example, and while two people *might* be able to weigh (winch up) such an anchor with the right gearing, it's going to take far longer and tire them sooner than (say) a crew of 10 on the winch.

The same goes for your sails; 'taking a reef', or shortening the sail so as to either slow the ship down in a strong wind or limit the chances of sudden gusts ripping off the mast was all done manually. That meant you had a crew of sailors up on the yard arms, literally pulling up a heavy canvas sail and tying it down so that less of the sail's surface was exposed to the wind. The larger the sail is, the less likely that you can do it with a limited crew, especially if you have to do it multiple times and quickly because you're caught in a squall.

As for pirates, that implies you might want cannon to defend yourself. Two people simply aren't going to be able to fire a single cannon, reload it and fire again at any reasonable speed, meaning that in a firefight you've lost almost instantly. Also, pirates in that era won't know if you have cargo or not, and in point of fact may not care as the most valuable thing you have is the ship itself. That ship will have been made out of a small forest of timber over the course of (potentially) years, and represents a massive investment in resources that makes it far more valuable than almost any cargo you could be carrying, except for perhaps gold or ambergris.

But, there are some accommodations you can make. If you use magic to do all the heavy lifting, then you could shorten sails and avoid reefs via that method. You could drop or weigh anchor that way also. Additionally, if you don't need to be fast, you could have a large ship with a single mast, meaning that you won't be as fast or as agile on the water, but you should be able to set your sails and rigging with a minimal crew. You'll get where you want to go eventually, but other ships will easily out-perform you.

If you have two experienced sailors on the ship, then you have navigation covered but also remember that at least one of those experienced sailors has to keep track of where you are at all times; no GPS in your world so you have to do things the old fashioned way by tracking direction, wind speeds, currents, et al and approximating your location on a map.

If however you want a simple boat that doesn't require a lot of experience to sail and still *looks* like a normal boat, then go for a [sloop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sloop). Single mast, some came with cannons back in the day, and in theory it scales up pretty well to get a large enough cargo around. In point of fact, IIRC they were used as supply ships by several navies during the times of the ships of the line. This would at least imply that they made good cargo ships that could be run with a minimal crew (leaving the bulk of the navy sailors on ships designed for combat).

The next size ship up would be something like a schooner or a corvette, depending on whether you're orienting yourself as a merchant or mercenary, but in both cases you're dealing with more masts, therefore more complexity (more ropes that can break or sails that can tear, etc.) and therefore in turn either more crew or more magic.

On the other hand, the sloop's hull could scale up somewhat if you're happy with a sluggish boat capable of handling a larger cargo with less crew. Ultimately the choice is yours on that front.

Comment: It's not even just operation that numbers are essential for.  Wooden sailing ships require constant maintenance.  Some of this is even skilled maintenance, so only the two with sailing experience could do it.  Sailing with a skeleton crew will eventually ruin your ship.  You simply can't keep up with wear and tear without a full complement.

Answer (score 4):

**Charter a ship crewed by NPCs**

Your players are not going to want to play at sailing a ship.  Have them charter a ship familiar with the area.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chartering_(shipping)

> A voyage charter is the hiring of a vessel and crew for a voyage
> between a load port and a discharge port. The charterer pays the
> vessel owner on a per-ton or lump-sum basis. The owner pays the port
> costs (excluding stevedoring), fuel costs and crew costs...
>
> A time charter is the hiring of a vessel
> for a specific period of time; the owner still manages the vessel but
> the charterer selects the ports and directs the vessel where to go.
> The charterer pays for all fuel the vessel consumes, port charges,
> commissions, and a daily hire to the owner of the vessel.

In the US, the Pilgrims did this with the Mayflower - they did not own the ship but hired it with captain and crew to take them to the New World.  After the Pilgrims were established, the ship left them and went back to England.

In your campaign, managing the ship can be left to the captain and crew of NPCs who know what they are doing.  They will take their direction from your players who hired them.  You as the DM get to play the part of these characters and they can be as interesting and involved as you want to make them.

Answer (score 2):

**Any sized vessel**

You have magic which means one mage with sufficient skill can virtually automate the ship given enough time and money. You have spells such as animate dead and animate object. You can create golems and summon creatures for crew. You can set the weather to favorable.

Not sure why you would want a large vessel when a small vessel is less noticeable, faster and easier to hide. Add a Mordenkainen’s Magnificent Mansion to it and your row boat has true style and comfort.

Comment: Wish I could give you more than +1 for mentioning the bit about the Mord's Mansion. I will try to drop clues to my party about that since there is a shop in the city that sells spell books.

Comment: I was wondering why a cargo vessel was required in a world that has Bags of Holding, but then if I were in a D&D world I’d have made my fortune by now by becoming an industrial shipping magnate, so...

Comment: Portable hole and a flying carpet and you can ship faster and cheaper than any ship

Answer (score 2):

## A ~50 foot sailboat

[image]

This is a US Navy 44 foot Mark II sailboat. They use them for training at the US Naval Academy, as well as in other places. Once upon a time I got a [D-qual](https://www.usna.edu/Sailing/lectures/navydQual.php#Navy%2044%20D%20Qual) as a Coastal Skipper for this boat, so if I can scratch my memory a bit, I might be able to provide some useful information here.

## Qualifications

I assert that you can sail this vessel with only two knowledgeable people and three more that have arms and legs. This is basically exactly how you run them at the Naval Academy, two instructors that know what they are doing and up to 10 other bodies. You might not be able to manage the [spinnaker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spinnaker) with five people, but that is mostly for show anyways; you can get near enough top speed with just the mainsail and jib up.

## Considerations

The technology of this boat is modern, but not excessively so. The rigging is not something that was seen in the world before 1800, with two [fore-and-aft](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fore-and-aft_rig) rigged sails; a mainsail and a [jib](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jib). Fore-and-aft rigged dhows were common in the Middle Ages in the Indian ocean; and jibs were used on the caravels of the Age of Discovery. The 44 has some nifty abilities (like an adjustable boom height) that you would not have with 1700s technology, but you wouldn't lose anything essential to the operation of the boat. Probably the biggest loss would be literal friction loss: the teflon [blocks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_(sailing)) with modern bearings make it much easier to operate large sails with one or two people compared to hand-made wooden blocks.

While a 50 foot ship doesn't seem that big, keep in mind [*La Nina*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ni%C3%B1a) (used by Columbus to cross the ocean blue) was only 50 foot. *La Nina* is stouter than the Navy 44's and has a deeper draft. It would hold more cargo and sleep more men (24 crewed *La Nina* while a 44 can sleep about 10). Consequentially, it would be much slower with the same rigging. So you can modify the boat's size as appropriate for the right combination of cargo and speed.  So if you can use this boat to sail from Spain to America in the most consequential sea voyage of our world, it is probably sufficient for your purposes.

## Information on how to sail

Check out the sailing guides [here](https://www.usna.edu/Sailing/lectures/navy44.php) for detailed instructions on how to perform basic maneuvers with the sailboat ([tacking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tacking_(sailing)), [gybing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jibe), [reefing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reefing), etc). These are the guides you use to teach midshipmen how to sail. You can see they have positions assigned, and most tasks can be completed with five people or less.

Rigging the mainsail and jib would be different with older technology, but they would be pretty similar to how the spinnaker is set and flown (and doused, which means taking it down) in the sailing instructions. However, those sails being smaller than the spinnaker, you could do it with 5 people.